# org.json.JSONException: No value for adr

Tags: android, json

I have one json file in my server and try to parse this.

I parse another Json file in my app successfuly but this code have exception.

this is my code :

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

              JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("tells");

              for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                TellModel tellModel = new TellModel();

                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                tellModel.setName(object.getString("name"));
                tellModel.setPhone(object.getString("phone"));
                tellModel.setAddress(object.getString("adr"));


                tellList.add(tellModel);
}
```

and Json file :

```
{
    "tells":[
        {
            "name":"دفتر رسیدگی به اسناد پزشکی استان تهران",
            "phone":"۶۶۴٣٧۶٩۶",
            "adr":"خیابان کارگر شمالی"
        },{

            "name":"اداره کل درمان سازمان بیمه تامین اجتماعی",
            "phone":"۶۶۴٢۵٢٨۴",
            "adr":"خیابان کارگر شمالی"
        },{
            "name":"اداره کمیسیون های پزشکی",
            "phone":"۶۶۶١٨٨٠٩",
            "adr":"تهران،سه راه آذری"
        },{
            "name":"بیمارستان میلاد",
            "phone":"٨٢٠٣٩",
            "adr":"بزرگراه همت"
        },{
            "name":"بیمارستان صدر",
            "phone":"٨٨٩۴۵۴٧۶",
            "adr":"میدان ولیعصر،خیابان کریم خان"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know why give this exception

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for adr
```

Comment: Is that all `JSON` or you have it more? Because maybe there is no `adr` node in all places which you are trying to parse

Comment: its working perfectly fine on my machine check you are using the same json

Comment: @Yupi this is all.

Comment: @YaserNiknam are you sure that exception thrown in that part?